# I am trying to call a URL from a local wordpress img file using a text widget

Tags: html, wordpress

I received permission to link to another site and they provided me their .jpg logo. I can get the URL to work but I cannot get the logo to pull from my site. I've tried numerous variations to the path of the logo file. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
<a href="http://www.pmi.org">"<img src="" alt="The PMI Logo is a registered mark of Project Management Institute, Inc." /></a>
```

I have also tried

[image]

And nothing seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? Are you sure you are using the 'text' editor in wordpress rather than the 'visual' editor?

```html
<img src="https://projectcontrolstools.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/PMI_Logo_Blue.jpg">
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. I'm trying to add this as text in a widget on the sidebar. It gives me the proper hyperlink but will not pull the image for some reason.

Comment: https://projectcontrolstools.com - Here you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: You are using some kind of CDN which is messing your whole site up it seems

Comment: I had someone do this to speed up wordpress and it seems to have messed everything up?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!